# At what point are props contents available (and are they reactive once they are)?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I pass data into a component via props:

```
<Comment :comment="currentCase.Comment" @comment="(c) => currentCase.Comment=c"></Comment>
```

`currentCase` is updated via a `fetch` call to an API during the setup of the component (the one that contains the line above)

The TS part of `<Comment>` is:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>

import { Comment } from 'components/helpers'
import {  ref, watch } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps<{comment: Comment}>()
const emit = defineEmits(['comment'])

console.log(props)
const dateLastUpdated = ref<string>(props.comment?.DateLastUpdated as string)
const content = ref<string>(props.comment?.Content as string)
watch(content, () => emit('comment', {DateLastUpdated: dateLastUpdated, Content: content}))

</script>
```

... where `Comment` is defined in `'components/helpers'` as

```
export class Comment {
  DateLastUpdated?: string
  Content?: string

  public constructor(init?: Partial<Case>) {
    Object.assign(this, init)
  }
}
```

`content` is used in the template, but is empty when the component is rendered. I added a `console.log()` to check whether the `props` were known - and what is passed is `undefined` at that point:

```
▸ Proxy {comment: undefined}
```

When looking at the value of the `props` once the application is rendered, their content is correct:

```
{
    "comment": {
        "DateLastUpdated": "",
        "Content": "comment 2 here"
    }
}
```

**My question: why is `comment` not updated when `props` are available (and when are their content available?)**

I also tried to push the update later in the reactive cycle, but the result is the same:

```
const dateLastUpdated = ref<string>('')
const content = ref<string>('')

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(props)
  dateLastUpdated.value = props.comment?.DateLastUpdated as string
  content.value = props.comment?.Content as string
  watch(content, () => emit('comment', {DateLastUpdated: dateLastUpdated, Content: content}))
})
```

Comment: You didn't show how the comp is used, this actually defines how the props behave.

Comment: @EstusFlask: I added the usage in the question at the top, thanks.

Comment: the first log is when component is loaded, not when instanciated nor mounted. 
By loaded I mean at this moment `import { Comment } from 'components/helpers'`

Comment: "currentCase is updated via a fetch call" - this answers the question. If it's initially available, thr prop is initially available. If it's not, the prop is not too. "content.value = props.comment?.Content as string"  - it's absolutely the same as `content.value = undefined`. content is not reactive and watching it won't do anything

Comment: @EstusFlask: OK, I understand that the `console.log()` call gives `undefined`- should have found out myself. But then - why wouldn't the **display** of `comment` in the template be updated? Why are you saying the `content` is not reactive?

Comment: Because it's not reactive indeed. The reactivity is destroyed (can be used intentionally for static props). `props.comment?.DateLastUpdated === undefined` at the time when it's accessed. You do `content.value = undefined`. You loose the connection with original variable when a value is primitive (not an object). There's no way how it could work differently in Vue or anywhere else, this is how JS works.

Answer (score 1):

Vue lifecycle creates component instances from parent to child, then mounts them in the opposite order. Prop value is expected to be available in a child if it's available at this time in a parent. If `currentCase` is set asynchronously in a parent, the value it's set to isn't available on component creation, it's a mistake to access it early.

This disables the reactivity:

```
content.value = props.comment?.Content as string
```

`props.comment?.Content === undefined` at the time when this code is evaluated,  it's the same as writing:

```
content.value = undefined;
```

Even if it weren't undefined, `content` wouldn't react to `comment` changes any way, unless `props.comment` is explicitly watched.

If `content` is supposed to always react to `props.comment` changes, it should be computed ref instead:

```
const content = computed(() => props.comment?.Content as string);
```

Otherwise it should be a ref and a watcher:

```
const content = ref();
const unwatch = watchEffect(() => {
  if (props.comment?.Content) {
    content.value = props.comment.Content;
    unwatch();
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. As for the last part: I would like `content` to acquire the value of the prop **once the parent gathers data from `fetch`** (and passes it as a prop), and then be able to edit it. This won't be possible with a computed value. I will have to think once again about how to combine an asynchronous "initial value" for the content, and then the ability to edit (and emit) this content. Thanks!

Comment: That's quite common case. Posted an example. Alternatively, you can prevent a child from rendering until all data is ready.