# Pass props to modal form, update, submit with Composition api Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I get props from parent with

```
const props = defineProps<{
  customer: Customer
}>()
```

Then I am const assigning to vModel, to be able to write/change data since props are read only.

```
model = useVModel(props, 'customer')
```

then on form  I am using

```
<input v-model="model.name" type="text" class="input" />
```

All i want is to modify data from props and `put` them to api.

Simple crud.
Edit:

Because I cant :

`<input v-model="model.name" :value="model.name" type="text" class="input" />`

I want to populate form via Props, then update them via v-model

I am trying to figure out, how to create a crud and pass props to modal for edit.

EDIT 2:

i tried add to ref()

```
let formData = ref({
  customer: {
    name: props.customer.name,
    department: props.customer.department,
  },
})
```

so I can use

```
<input v-model="formdata.customer.name" type="text" class="input" />
```

but I get:

```
EditCustomer.vue:66 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly and what is the question? There's no useVModel in Vue, if you use third-party util, this needs to be listed

Comment: @EstusFlask I used useVModel, trying to make it work, ignore it. check my edit. Just want to pass data via props to modal form, and update them

Comment: What is useVModel? Is it this one? https://vueuse.org/core/usevmodel/ Then it can be seen it needs `emit` as well, because two-way binding cannot work without it.

Comment: Yeah, but I dont really need two-way, I just got frustrated and tried everything. If I use `props.customer.name` in  v-model I get `Unexpected mutation of "props" prop.eslintvue/no-mutating-props`. I am missing somehow whole concept.

Comment: You actually do if you need to modify parent's value inside a child.

Comment: You actually do if you need to modify parent's value inside a child. If the intention is to get initial value from a parent and modify it in a child but not in a parent then this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71619219/3731501  needs to be used instead of two-way binding.

Comment: I understand that, but I am trying to get ahead of backend logic, when I update data in modal, after I click save, post data to api do I need to emit to parent to tell that data has been changed or it refreshes data via reactive. Forgive my ignorance, but on options api we had data(){} and somehow it worked .

Comment: The thing that two-way binding changes is that instead of modifying data in a child directly, a child tells to a parent 'it's not my own data and I don't have a right to modify it, but I'd like to', and a parent says nothing but modifies and gives updated data to a child through a prop. This is done this way because modifying it directly results in design problems and bad code, this is the lesson that Vue learned from Angular. You shouldn't but can modify deeply nested data like props.customer.name in a child, "Unexpected mutation" is just linter error that can be disabled at your risk.

Comment: This still works with composition api, this part is no different from `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props can't be modified shallowly like `props.foo =`, and shouldn't be modified deeply like `props.foo.bar =`. The only suitable way is to send an event to parent component where a value that is passed through a prop exists, so it could modify it for a child. This is what [`v-model` does](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html).

There's no way how `useVModel(props, 'foo')` function could be written to work like that, because the arguments it's provided with only allow to modify `props.foo`, which is readonly. In order to make it work, `useVModel` needs to implement two-way binding, so an event with updated value could be changed in a parent, so it needs to be able to send events. This is what the [documentation](https://vueuse.org/core/usevmodel/) lists:

```
const data = useVModel(props, 'data', emit)

console.log(data.value) // props.data
data.value = 'foo' // emit('update:data', 'foo')
```

The example with `ref` won't work because `props.customer.name` is accessed directly inside setup function, this breaks the reactivity and also results in an error in case `props.customer === undefined` at this moment.

Comment: I need to get to basics, of understanding this better. Thanks for driving me in right direction.

Comment: I was overthinking everything, thanks again :)

Comment: Glad you sorted this out